# VBA - Verification and simplication of combined code

Tags: vba

I've tried to combine different VBA codes into only one to avoid multiple macros. It works (I get the desired output) but I'd like to know if the code will always work (e.g. if the sheets are not well defined) and if I can simply it (reduce the number of code rows). Here is it :

```
Sub test2()
Dim sht As Worksheet, cell As Range, areaToTrim As Range, LastRow As Long, lstrow As Long, lrow As Long, sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JDE_Greece")
sht.Activate
Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
Sheets("JDE_Greece").Cells(1, 1) = "KEY"
Range("I1").EntireColumn.Insert
sht.Cells(1, 9) = "Quantity JDE (aggregated)"
Range("J1").EntireColumn.Insert
sht.Cells(1, 10) = "Item Code CDL (decomposed)"
Range("K1").EntireColumn.Insert
sht.Cells(1, 11) = "Item Code CDL"
Range("L1").EntireColumn.Insert
sht.Cells(1, 12) = "Quantity CDL (decomposed)"
Range("M1").EntireColumn.Insert
sht.Cells(1, 13) = "Quantity CDL"
Range("N1").EntireColumn.Insert
sht.Cells(1, 14) = "Overwrite (abs in vol)"
Range("O1").EntireColumn.Insert
sht.Cells(1, 15) = "Overwrite (abs in %)"
Range("P1").EntireColumn.Insert
sht.Cells(1, 16) = "Hit/Miss"
Set areaToTrim = Sheets("JDE_Greece").Range("G2:G" & LastRow)
For Each cell In areaToTrim
cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
Next cell
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
Range("J2:J" & LastRow).Value = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(G2,'mapping codes'!A:B,2,0)),G2,VLOOKUP(G2,'mapping codes'!A:B,2,0))"
Range("J2:J" & LastRow).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
Range("K2:K" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(""*""&J2&""*"",CDL_Greece!D:D,1,0)),J2,VLOOKUP(""*""&J2&""*"",CDL_Greece!D:D,1,0))"
Range("K2:K" & LastRow).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
Range("A2").Formula = "=K2&B2"
Range("A2").Copy Range("A3:A" & LastRow)
lstrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("I2:I" & lstrow).Value = "=SUMIFS(H:H,G:G,G2,A:A,A2)"
Range("I2:I" & lstrow).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:M" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("L2:L" & lrow).Value = "=VLOOKUP(A2,CDL_Greece!A:I,9,0)"
Range("L2:L" & lrow).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("M2:M" & lrow).Value = "=IF(ISNA(L2),VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(""*""&G2&""*"",CDL_Greece!D:D,1,0)&B2,CDL_Greece!A:I,9,0),L2)"
Range("M2:M" & lrow).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("N2:N" & lrow).Value = "=ABS(M2-I2)"
Range("O2:O" & lrow).Value = "=ABS(I2-M2)/M2"
Range("O2:O" & lrow).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
Range("P2:P" & lrow).Value = "=IF(M2=I2,1,0)"
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 51)
Range("B1:H1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 102)
Range("I1:M1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
Range("N1:P1").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JDE_Greece")
Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mismatches")
With sht
    lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="#N/A"
    .Range("A1:P" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
End With
sht1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With sht2
    .Name = "Summary DRP"
    .Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Instructions")
End With
With sht
    .Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<>#N/A"
    .Range("A1:P" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
End With
sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End Sub
```

Sorry in advance if it's a bit long (I've even removed my personal comments..).
Thanks a lot for your expertise :)

Comment: This would probably be better suited to Code Review:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As a most immediate answer here: look into removing `Select/Activate`. Many of your `Ranges` are not fully qualified and if for whichever reason focus switches to a different sheet then this macro will not work. And as Darren mentioned: working code should go to CodeReview. But try removing `Select/Activate` before going there.

Comment: Ok, thanks both of you ! I'll try first to remove Select/Activate then go to the other site :)

Comment: But, do you have an example where I can remove the select ? Especially when I want to select one column, copy paste special and set a format. I imagine the rest can be derived from this example.. Thanks!

Comment: Normally you can just replace `Selection` with actual range: `Columns("G:G").NumberFormat = "@"`. I would also recommend to do that within `With...End With` for your `sht` to ensure that it is running against the right worksheet.

Comment: As @VictorK said - look at `With...End With`.  _Sample code_, taking into account you've got `sht` defined as a worksheet:  `sht.Range("A1").Copy: sht.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` - copies values from A1 to A2 (note - these are two lines separated by a `:`).  _Example 2_:   plain copy/paste `sht.Range("A1").Copy sht.Range("A2")` - basically anything that references a range is preceded by the sheet reference.

Comment: Actually, using your exact code - `sht.Cells(1, 10) = "Item Code CDL (decomposed)"`.  This line wouldn't need a Select statement.  You could have another sheet selected and it will place that text in cell J1 of the JDE_Greece sheet.